# Fetching values of key stored in a column of a dataframe?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe that looks like below:

```
user_id event_desc
100013  {'firebase_screen': '/product-popup', 'banner_id': '9260'}
100022  {'firebase_screen': '/product-popup', 'banner_id': '9152'}
100076  {'firebase_screen_id': '-1531185473150377061'}
100076  {'banner_id': '8567', 'firebase_screen': '/product-popup'}
```

I am trying to fetch the values of key banner_id.

So, output is like below:

```
user_id event_desc                                            banner_id
100013  {'firebase_screen': '/product-popup', 'banner_id': '9260'}  9260
100022  {'firebase_screen': '/product-popup', 'banner_id': '9152'}  9151
100076  {'firebase_screen_id': '-1531185473150377061'}               Nan
100076  {'banner_id': '8567', 'firebase_screen': '/product-popup'}  8567
```

I am using the below code.

```
df['banner_id'] = df['event_desc'].apply(lambda x: x.get('banner_id'))
```

It gives the error:

'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 0):

As long as those are not stored as strings, it works:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
[100013,  {'firebase_screen': '/product-popup', 'banner_id': '9260'}],
[100022,  {'firebase_screen': '/product-popup', 'banner_id': '9152'}],
[100076 , {'firebase_screen_id': '-1531185473150377061'}],
[100076 , {'banner_id': '8567', 'firebase_screen': '/product-popup'}]], columns =['user_id', 'event_desc'])


df['banner_id'] = df['event_desc'].apply(lambda x: x.get('banner_id'))
```

My guess, based on your error is that column is not a column of dictionaries, but rather a column of strings:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
[100013,  "{'firebase_screen': '/product-popup', 'banner_id': '9260'}"],
[100022,  "{'firebase_screen': '/product-popup', 'banner_id': '9152'}"],
[100076 , "{'firebase_screen_id': '-1531185473150377061'}"],
[100076 , "{'banner_id': '8567', 'firebase_screen': '/product-popup'}"]], columns =['user_id', 'event_desc'])


df['banner_id'] = df['event_desc'].apply(lambda x: x.get('banner_id'))

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

So if that's the case, you'll want to use:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame([
[100013,  "{'firebase_screen': '/product-popup', 'banner_id': '9260'}"],
[100022,  "{'firebase_screen': '/product-popup', 'banner_id': '9152'}"],
[100076 , "{'firebase_screen_id': '-1531185473150377061'}"],
[100076 , "{'banner_id': '8567', 'firebase_screen': '/product-popup'}"]], columns =['user_id', 'event_desc'])


df['banner_id'] = df['event_desc'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x).get('banner_id'))
```

**ADDITIONAL:**

```
import pandas as pd
import ast


def eval_code(code):
    parsed = ast.parse(code, mode='eval')
    fixed = ast.fix_missing_locations(parsed)
    compiled = compile(fixed, '<string>', 'eval')
    return eval(compiled)


df = pd.DataFrame([
[100013,  "{'firebase_screen': '/product-popup', 'banner_id': '9260'}"],
[100022,  "{'firebase_screen': '/product-popup', 'banner_id': '9152'}"],
[100076 , "{'firebase_screen_id': '-1531185473150377061'}"],
[100076 , "{'banner_id': '8567', 'firebase_screen': '/product-popup'}"]], columns =['user_id', 'event_desc'])


df['banner_id'] = df['event_desc'].apply(lambda x: eval_code(x).get('banner_id'))
```

Comment: using the above gives me "ValueError: malformed node or string:" error

Comment: is there a way to share your exact dataframe? maybe just first 5 to 10 rows?

Comment: i can mail u..id pls?

Comment: df['banner_id'] = df['event_desc'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(str(x)).get('banner_id')) .. this worked ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
df['banner_id'] = df['event_desc'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(str(x)).get('banner_id'))
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation as to why this is a solution to OP's problem. Code only answers are discouraged on SO as they do not help OP or future visitors of the site.